# Load CSV files to Azure SQL Warehouse via curl

Tags: sql-server, bash, azure, curl

Can anyone provide an example using curl (I'm writing a bash shell script) to upload a CSV to Azure SQL Warehouse? I'm frequently generating CSV exports on Ubuntu virtual instances and need a method to upload to Azure SQL Warehouse via HTTPS rather than other means that require custom network configurations to allow the outbound traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -X PUT -T ./{file.dat} -H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" "https://{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/backups/{file.dat}?{sas-token}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to create a custom API in azure to call and insert the data. An easier solution may be Microsoft Flow if you have an O365 account or Zapier if not. You could export the csv to a cloud storage account (Onedrive, dropbox etc) the use one of those tools to import it to azure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Was hoping there was something built-in already that would allow for this but it shouldn't be a big effort to use one of the suggestions you made.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe do something like this.

Upload to blob storage uisng this script. This is pure HTTP call to blob using PowerShell but you can produce the same result using bash/batch and curl.

```
# Storage Account
$accountname=""
$container=""

# Access Key
$key = ""

# Blob details
$fileContent = "content"
$blobName="file.txt"


$bloburl = "https://$accountname.blob.core.windows.net/"
$BlobOperation = "PUT"
$filelen = $fileContent.Length
$RESTAPI_URL = "https://$accountname.blob.core.windows.net/$container/$blobName";
$date=(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$datestr=$date.ToString("R");
$strtosign = "$BlobOperation`n`n`n$filelen`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob`nx-ms-date:$datestr`nx-ms-version:2015-04-05`n/"
$strtosign = $strtosign + $accountname + "/" + $container + "/" +$blobName

write-host $strtosign

[byte[]]$dataBytes = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8).GetBytes($strtosign)
$hmacsha256 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha256.Key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($key)
$sig = [Convert]::ToBase64String($hmacsha256.ComputeHash($dataBytes))
$authhdr = "SharedKey $accountname`:$sig"


$RequestHeader = @{
    "Authorization" = $authhdr;
    "x-ms-date" = $datestr;
    "x-ms-version" = "2015-04-05";
    "x-ms-blob-type" = "BlockBlob"
}

$RESTResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RESTAPI_URL -Method put -Headers $RequestHeader -Body $fileContent)

write-host "Success >>" $RESTAPI_URL
```

Then. Create very simple Data Factory flow which triggers on new blob and load data to SQL DW. If you want to learn ADF quickly I can recommend my video here

https://youtu.be/EpDkxTHAhOs

Comment: What in the video?

Comment: It's Azure Data Factory introduction video. It has also demo on how to load CSV from blob to SQL.